# how can we show a text/message using php

Tags: php, html, css, php-5.3

I've got an `admin.php` file where I am inserting data and image into a MySQL database, but in  the php part there is an `echo` to show but it is not showing. For example:

```
if(!isset($_FILES['image1']))
{
    echo '<p>Please select a file</p>';
}
```

This file has another css file for design .Is this creating any problem?

Comment: if you put the echo above the if statement, does it show then?

Comment: Where is the line that is meant to display the file? Something similar to `<?php echo '<img src="..."'> ?>`.

Comment: there is no message for any echo whether it is into the if statement or below /above the statement.actually the total file is like below:<html><body><form><input type="" value="" name=""></form></body><?php?></html>

Answer (score 1):

```
 if(!isset($_FILES['image1']))
 {
 echo '<p>Please select a file</p>';
 }
```

This means that the file from field "image1", was not selected and was not uploaded. So this will appear all time, untill you are submiting a real file.

About css. Look for the html code, if you cann't find the `<p>Please select a file</p>` line anywhere, then the css is not guilty, trouble is in php. If there is the `<p>Please select a file</p>` line in html, so it can be invisible by styling in css file, so digg in that way.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because `$_FILES['image1']` is set when you are posting the form.

What you want is probably:

```
if(false === empty($_FILES['image1']['name']))
{
    echo '<p>Please select a file</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a var_dump of the $_FILES variable to make sure it is set and also check the layout of the array. Once you can see the arrow of output you should know what to check against.

Also, to see if CSS is the culprit check the source code of the output in a browser. Or, a better option would be to check it in something like Firefox's firebug plugin.